# How to provide password in bash file to be executed in terminal

Tags: file, bash, ubuntu

I installed **wondershaper** on Ubuntu, it's a program that throttles the Internet speed, I have mean siblings who use all bandwidth when I'm not home, and my Internet is limited, I want to create a bash file that will run at start up, means when they turn on the computer, these are the codes which I usually type in the terminal

```
sudo wondershaper eth0 3 3
//It asks me for my password

The bash file will be something like this
#!/bin/bash
sudo wondershaper eth0 3 3
```

but what is the code that gives him the password when he asks for it in the terminal? without me typing it?

Comment: Why not just run the script in root? There's no need to use sudo, and thus it won't prompt for the password. Also, if your mean siblings are clever siblings, they won't be able to disable the script without the root password.

Comment: Can you write the correct codes please? I'm a newbie :(

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, leaving your password in plain text is a bad idea. It's much better to have this script run as root as part of the init scripts.

Your script relies on the `sudo` command to get temporary superuser privileges.

Instead of having your script run on your normal user account, run it on root's account. Then, you won't need to give your password to be granted root privileges. You'll be running the script from `/etc/init.d`, which is Ubuntu's directory for start-up scripts. You'll probably want to add it to a pre-existing script like `rc.local` (a file that is executed after all other init scripts have run).

Omit the `sudo` parts of your script (e.g. `sudo echo` just becomes `echo`), as root doesn't need to ask for superuser privileges. And that's it!

You said you were new to Linux, so here are two resources to help you get started:

- [Wikipedia - what sudo is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo)
- ["Get to know the /etc/init.d directory"](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/)

Comment: Sorry. That is not enough. Not every file in that folder is executed. It depends on the run level. He should add that command in /etc/init.d/rc.local or he has to create a new whole startup script.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I sort of skimmed over actually configuring the setup script. I'll edit my answer to address that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It's insecure because you should write the password in clear on a file.

You have to change /etc/sudoers to let your user use sudo without a password, add this line:

`$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/wondershaper`

Where $USER is your username.

Otherwise, you can add that on /etc/init.d/rc.local and so it will be ran as root during boot.

Comment: It looks like he only needs sudo access to one command, not all of them.

Comment: So I would advice to put the command in an init script. I don't use ubuntu but I think that /etc/init.d/rc.local will work.

Comment: @jordanm, yes, you're right. But I don't know exactly where wondershaper has it's bin. Is that path right?

Comment: Letting all sudoers use sudo without any password is horrible practice.

Comment: @MartinTrigaux, I don't have it on my system... and I'm running slackware... I won't compile it for this answer. :P